# Gridview is showing time as 30/12/1899 07:15:00 when importing from excel sheet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, gridview, spreadsheet

I am importing an excel 2007 sheet to a Gridview. When importing it displays 07:15 as 30/12/1899 07:15:00

I need it to show only the 07:15 part.

Help!

Comment: Look at date formatting here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If changing the date format does not work, try **Text to Columns**. It will be under the "data" tab. Process is

1. Data - Text to Columns
2. "Fixed Width"
3. Move the line to where you want to slice the date in half (after "30/12/1899")
4. "Finish"

The date will be sliced in half and you'll now have two columns: one with the date and one with the time. Delete the date column.